# Изменить размер изображения с формы на django

Tags: python, django

Есть форма на django, которая загружает картинку. Нужно после отправки формы перед хранением картинки на сервер изменить ее размеры, например на такие 200х200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте бибилиотеку для работы с ImageField, например, https://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/

Она сохраняет оригинал изображения, но это полезно - например, если захотите впоследствии изменить размер изображения на 300х300.